# How to exclude one album from the gallery?

Tags: wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I wanna somehow remove one album from the gallery.
right now i am using [album compact], in this its showing all the albums. But my requirement is something like i wanna exclude one album from this gallery. How can i do this?

Comment: please post a code snipe s that we can have a look how you are displaying albums ... thanks

Comment: [album compact] this is the only thing that i am using in the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [album id=x template=compact]